# archives had fatal errors. как узнать подробнее в чем ошибки?

Tags: shell

Распаковал все архивы в папке командой `unzip "*.zip"`
После распаковки получил сообщение:

```
54 archives were successfully processed.
12 archives had fatal errors.
```

Как узнать поподробнее с какими архивами, файлами случились эти ошибки?

И еще вопрос: почему под виндой архивы распаковываются без проблем, а после закачки на сервер и распаковки выдают вот такую ошибку ? Из за чего может быть такое?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
for i in "*.zip"; do echo Распаковывается архив $i; unzip $i; done
```

> а после закачки на сервер и распаковки выдают вот такую ошибку ? Из за чего может быть такое?

Такое может быть из-за того, что во время закачки на сервер произошли ошибки. Сравните контрольные суммы после передачи. Переданных файлов и исходных.

Comment: А как насчёт неподдерживаемых алгоритмов сжатия?

Comment: правильнее и короче — `for i in "*.zip"`. ваша же конструкция `for i in \`ls *.zip\`` сработает некорректно, например, при наличии пробелов в именах файлов.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: спасибо, исправил.